# Changing field names in database

Tags: upgrade, fields

I just want to change some of the field names and drop-down option names in my membership database.  Where to I go to get started?

Comment: may help get helpful answers if you provide some specific examples. do you mean custom fields, or out of the box fields.

Comment: Provide more deatils about your question and requirement. May be someone has better alternative solution for the same.